# find difference in both sheetA and sheetB and paster it in another excel sheet

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyverse

Hi brothers and sisters

Greetings to you all

Please I need your humble assistance

I have 2 different excel sheets in the excel workbook

I have some records in sheetA but not in sheetB and also have in sheetB, not in sheetA
Using ID_1 column in sheetA against Source_ID in sheetB

see table below

this is sheetA

| Merchant | value | ID_1 | net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sandy | 500 | 2KJH2BH2 | 98 |
| plain | 501 | 2KJH2BH3 | 42 |
| munfy | 502 | 2KJH2BH4 | 43 |
| plyrr | 503 | 2KJH2BH5 | 44 |
| plyrr | 504 | 2KJH2BH6 | 45 |
| munfy | 505 | 2KJH2BH7 | 46 |

This is sheetB

| Merchant | value | source | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sandy | 500 | 2KJH2BH2 | 98 |
| plain | 501 | 2KJH2BH3 | 42 |
| munfy | 502 | efjerbf7 | 43 |
| plyrr | 503 | kelnklnv | 44 |
| plyrr | 504 | 2KJH2BH6 | 45 |

what I want is compare both sheet A and B using ID_1 in sheetA against source_ID in sheetB
give me whats in sheetA that's not in sheetB using ID_1 open another excelsheet and paste it there

give me whats sheetB that's not in sheetA using source_ID open another excel sheet and past it there

I want it all to be in the same excel workbook that's why I said open another sheet paste the missing records there

Comment: do you want this to be done in R or Excel? your tags are not in line with the description

Comment: i want it done in R then later export the end result to excel

Comment: @user16087142 the offered answers do not solve your task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you use `anti_join()` from dplyr, then `write.xlsx`

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

sheetA<-readxl::read_excel('imput_file.xlsx', sheet = 'sheetA')
sheetB<-readxl::read_excel('imput_file.xlsx', sheet = 'sheetB')

sheetA %>% anti_join(sheetB, by=c('ID1' = 'source')) %>% write.xlsx(file="output_file.xlsx", sheetName="sheetA", row.names = F)
sheetB %>% anti_join(sheetA, by=c('source' = 'ID1')) %>% write.xlsx(file="output_file.xlsx", sheetName="sheetB", row.names = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

one alternative for handling multiple page excel files is the openxlsx package:

```
library(openxlsx)
# where to read the data from (change acordingly)
path <- ".../MY_EXCEL.xlsx"
# read in data to object, conserving formating etc.
wb <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(file = path)
# read specific data
df1 <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(wb, sheet = 1)
df2 <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(wb, sheet = 2)
# use the anti_join
df3 <- df1 %>%
    dplyr::anti_join(df2, by = c("ID_1" = "source"))
# create new page in wb object
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "sheetC")
# write data
openxlsx::writeData(wb = wb, sheet = "sheetC", x = df3)

# repeating for newt sheet
df4 <- df2 %>%
    dplyr::anti_join(df1, by = c("source" = "ID_1"))

openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "sheetD")
openxlsx::writeData(wb = wb, sheet = "sheetD", x = df4)

# overwrite existing excel file
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb = wb, file = path, overwrite = TRUE)
```

You could resume this in a nice function to reduce the number of code lines...